# $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_{|x|>\varepsilon}\frac{e^{-(t-x)^2}}{x}dx=?$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

I'm computing this integral

$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_{|x|>\varepsilon}\frac{e^{-(t-x)^2}}{x}dx=?$$

I'm not sure that its integral whether exist. How could I solve it?

Thanks for attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Hilbert transform 
$$PV\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{t-x}dx=-i\pi e^{-t^2}Erf(it).$$
See M.L. Glasser, JCAM [\bf 10}, 293 (1984).

Comment: could you please tell me which book? I cannot find it.

Comment: JCAM=Journal of Computational Mathematics